# Pytest BDD - one feature file with multiple scenarios

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pytest, bdd

I have a feature file with 2 scenarios. From my test file, when I run with pytest, the first scenario is being checked(pass/fail) only. The test file never goes to the second scenario. Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

I am putting a draft of how my code looks like:

```
feature file:
Feature: ....

Scenario: Scenario 1
 Given
 When
 Then

Scenario: Scenario 2
 Given
 When
 Then
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and (2) Why is voting important? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.  -- Happy Coding!

Comment: You are putting a draft of your code? Can you just copy and paste it? Finally, are you talking about a gherkin file?

Comment: never mind. found the solution

Comment: i didn't declare the function after the second scenario on my test file

Answer (score 0):

You can use "scenarios" this feature. it loads all scenarios from your feature file.

For exampl:
scenarios('xxx.feature')